# prepared statement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

how  can i write prepared statement instead of this: please help me

```
String qry= "INSERT INTO 
Registration1(RegistrationNo,Date,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BirthDate,BloodGroup) VALUES('"+regno+"','"+dt+"','"+nm+"','"+place+"','"+kul+"','"+gotra+"','"+kswami+"','"+raddr+"','"+pincode+"','"+stdcd+"','"+tele+"','"+mno+"','"+email+"','"+website+"','"+education+"','"+branch+"','"+bdt+"','"+bloodgrp+"')";
stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Registration1(RegistrationNo,Date,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BirthDate,BloodGroup) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

int col = 1;
stmt.setString(col++, regno);
stmt.setDate(col++, new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime()));  // assuming dt is a java.util.Date
(etc)

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to have a Date column as a String if it were possible to use the proper type.

Comment: Obviously you use the correct types in the set????() calls.  But since the OP didn't give any useful information about the types in his table, I used setString.

Comment: Oh, so you inferred it just as I did PreparedStatement earlier?  For shame.

Comment: And it wasn't so "obvious" until I made the comment and you edited your code.  You had a Date bound using setString, hence the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
    `enter code here`you can use prepared statement of insertion like..


         Connection MyCon=null;
         PreparedStatement Ps=null;
try{
          myCon=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","student","student");   
       // these are string from where we can take inputs .
         String Fname;
         String Lname;
         String email;
         String department;
         String Salary;


         Fname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter First Name");
         Lname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Last Name");
         email=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Your Email");
         department=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Department Name");
         Salary=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Salary Name");

            **String insertion="insert into employees"
                   + "(first_name, last_name, email, department ,salary )"+"values "
                    + "(?,?,?,?,?)";**

             **Ps=(PreparedStatement) MyCon.prepareStatement(insertion);
               Ps.setString(1,Fname);
                 Ps.setString(2,Lname);
                 Ps.setString(3,email);
                 Ps.setString(4,department);
                 Ps.setString(5,Salary);

        Ps.executeUpdate();**
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printtrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use this template:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con .prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnNmae1, ColumnNmae2, ColumnNmae3...) VALUES (?,?,?...);
    pstmt.setType(1, value);
    pstmt.setType(2, value);
    pstmt.setType(3, value);
    etc.
```

in the prepared statemnt you need to use exactly the same amount oof question mark as the columns you manchined in the statment.

for each question mark you shoukd setValue, you need to choose the right set for eac value typr, there is setString setInt etc...

In your specific case it should look like that:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con .prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO TableName (RegistrationNo,Date,SeniorPerson...) VALUES (?,?,?...);
pstmt.setString(1, regno);
pstmt.setDate(2, Date);
pstmt.setString(3, SeniorPerson);
etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Yours is an example of how to NOT use `PreparedStatement`.

Here's a better idea:

```
// Here's a PreparedStatement to satisfy the person who downvoted.
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement();
// I might have missed a '?' - you should check it.
String qry= "INSERT INTO    Registration1(RegistrationNo,Date,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BirthDate,BloodGroup) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
// Bind the variables here
stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
```

You should go through [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) carefully.

Comment: How do you bind variables when you don't have a PreparedStatement to bind them to?  All you have there is a String.

Comment: BTW: I didn't give you the downvote.  I think the link to the Sun^WOracle tutorial balances out the lack of a PreparedStatement in your answer.

Comment: You don't know from the posted code that stmt doesn't refer to a PreparedStatement.  Your comment is unwarranted.

Comment: If you call "stmt.executeUpdate(qry)", then the statement isn't *prepared*.  You're just using the features of the superclass Statement.